# Mosquitto no websocket connection since version 02.0.12 (Windows specific)

Tags: websocket, connection, mqtt, mosquitto

today I wanted to set up a simple mosquitto server on my windows machine for testing.
I am using "MQTT Explorer" for convenience and downloaded the latest 2.0.14 mosquitto binaries for windows (I am using Windows 10).
However I am unable to connect to my local server with Mosquitto 2.0.14, 2.0.13 and 2.0.12.

My connection is successful with 2.0.11, 2.0.10, 2.0.9a and 2.0.7 but these versions only work when I also have a standard http listener in the config (which I do not want since later on I only want one wss listener).

This is the config I am using:

```
allow_anonymous true

#HTTP listener
listener 1883

#Websocket standard listener
listener 9001
protocol websockets
```

This is the server output I get when using 2.0.14, 2.0.13 or 2.0.12 after my connection failed:
[image]

And this is the output when using 2.0.11, 2.0.10, 2.0.9a or 2.0.7 but without the http listener in the config:
[image]

Can anyone reproduce this behaviour or tell me where I messed up?

Comment: I have duplicated your issue; adding `socket_domain ipv4` at the end of the config fixes this for me (with `2.0.14` - this should not be needed but....)

Comment: Thanks a lot, great workaround!
Can you elaborate on how you came to this solution?

There is already a github issue raised for this issue I just found now: https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/2425

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the comments I was able to duplicate the issue with Mosquitto 2.0.14 and an [issue](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/2425) has been raised.

A workaround is to add `socket_domain ipv4` into the configuration - e.g.

```
allow_anonymous true

listener 9001
protocol websockets
socket_domain ipv4
```

I came across option in [this issue](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/2158) and it does appear to fix the issue. Note that I have not looked into why this fixes the issue so this should be considered a temporary workaround until the issue mentioned above is updated.