# Mosquitto 2.0.14 with Websockets

Tags: amazon-ec2, websocket, mqtt, mosquitto

I have a Mosquitto 2.0.14 broker running in a Windows server 2019. I can connect to it over port 8883 using mqtts protocol with SSL enabled. I can also connect to it on port 1883 without SSL.
Now I want to connect using Websockets. So I added a listener as:

```
listener 9001
protocol websockets
allow_anonymous false
password_file C:\mosquitto\password.txt
http_dir C:\mosquitto\http_dir
set_tcp_nodelay true
```

I also tried without `http_dir` and `set_tcp_nodelay`. I have tried with and without SSL certificates.
I have port 9001 opened in windows firewall as well as on AWS EC2 instance security groups.

[image: This is when I run the mosquitto broker]

[image: Port 9001 is being used by mosquitto]

But when I try to connect to the broker using `ws://broker.mysite.com:9001` or `ws://broker.mysite.com:9001/mqtt` nothing happens. No error, no connection. Mosquitto does not show any logs even though I can see the request coming in using WireShark. I am really stuck here. please help me out.

**Edit:**
I have tried to connect using MQTTX, MQTT Explorer and MQTTBox Chrome App.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71527801/edit) the question to show the code you are using to try and connect

Comment: I have tried to connect using MQTTX, MQTT Explorer and MQTTBox Chrome App. @hardillb

Comment: Where exactly are you running wireshark? on the client or on the machine with the broker?

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70643455/mosquitto-no-websocket-connection-since-version-02-0-12/70674266#70674266) and [this issue](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/2425) may be relevant. Try adding `socket_domain ipv4` under the `listener` in `mosquitto.conf`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per the comments this issue has been noted previously (in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70643455/mosquitto-no-websocket-connection-since-version-02-0-12/70674266#70674266)), however I figure its worth repeating here to aid others who experience the problem.

In short - there appears to be a bug in Mosquitto versions 2.0.12, 2.0.13 & 2.0.14 running on Windows when listening for websocket connections. Whilst the broker appears to be listening (on the correct port) it does not, in fact, accept connections (and nothing is logged). I have not investigated in detail but the cause is going to be something about the way the socket is being configured.

There is a workaround - add `socket_domain ipv4` under the `listener` e.g.

```
listener 9001
protocol websockets
allow_anonymous false
password_file C:\mosquitto\password.txt
http_dir C:\mosquitto\http_dir
set_tcp_nodelay true
socket_domain ipv4
```

See [this issue](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/issues/2425) in the github repo for more information.

Comment: I can connect to the broker after adding `socket_domain ipv4` in config. But I have to connect using SSL/TLS. I have the certificates & all works well if I use MQTTX and MQTT Explorer clients. But when I try to connect using `wss://` protocol from the browser using MQTTBox chrome app or MQTT.js library, it doesn't work. Without SSL/TLS `ws://` protocol works in the browser. Any suggestions about that?

Comment: It's probably worth raising another question about that (with info on the certificate (self-signed?), broker logs, code etc).