# Cannot access eclipse mosquitto mqtt from reactjs app

Tags: reactjs, websocket, mqtt, mosquitto

I am running an Eclipse Mosquitto MQTT broker V 2.0.15 in a Docker container. I want to access it from a reactjs application. I can connect successfully to the mqtt from a device using mqtt protocoll. But when trying to use websockets from react it fails. It spams the container log saying it closes its connection over and over again.

mosquitto.conf:

```
per_listener_settings true
persistence true
persistence_location /mosquitto/data/
#log_dest file /mosquitto/log/mosquitto.log

## Authentication ##
allow_anonymous false
listener 8885
password_file /mosquitto/config/password.txt

# websockets connections from react
listener 9001
protocol websockets
socket_domain ipv4
```

react.js application:

```
import React, { useState, Fragment } from 'react';
import mqtt from "precompiled-mqtt";

var options = {
    protocol: 'ws',
    username: 'smart_home_mqtt_user',
    password: 'testtest',
    clientId: 'react-client',
};
var client = mqtt.connect('ws://192.168.0.160:9001',options);

client.on('connect', () => {
    console.log("CONNECTED to broker");
});
//  MQTT topic
client.subscribe('test');

function MqttDash() {
    var note;
    client.on('message', function (topic, message) {
        note = message.toString();
        // Updates React state with message 
        setMsg(note);
        console.log(note);
        client.end();
    });

    // Sets default React state 
    const [msg, setMsg] = useState(<Fragment><em>...</em></Fragment>);

    return (
        <div >   
                <h1>Hello MQTT in React</h1>
                <p>The message payload is: {msg}</p>     
        </div>
    );
}

export default MqttDash;
```

Output in mosquitto container log:

```
1664520991: mosquitto version 2.0.15 starting
1664520991: Config loaded from /mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf.
1664520991: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8885.
1664520991: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 8885.
1664520991: Opening websockets listen socket on port 9001.
1664520991: mosquitto version 2.0.15 running
1664521055: Client react-client closed its connection.
1664521056: Client react-client closed its connection.
1664521057: Client react-client closed its connection.
1664521058: Client react-client closed its connection.
1664521059: Client react-client closed its connection.
1664521060: Client react-client closed its connection.
```

Comment: Move the `client.subscribe()` to in the `client.on('connect'...)` callback (because that is the right place for it) and add a `client.on('error', (err) =>{})` to get insight into why the client is closing the connection

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by changing my mosquitto.conf to:

```
per_listener_settings true
persistence true
persistence_location /mosquitto/data/
#log_dest file /mosquitto/log/mosquitto.log

## Authentication ##
listener 8885
allow_anonymous false
password_file /mosquitto/config/password.txt

# websockets connections from react
listener 9001
protocol websockets
socket_domain ipv4
allow_anonymous false
password_file /mosquitto/config/password.txt
```

Comment: More info in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71541392/11810946).